# ajax content with jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have `show_place.php` and two ajax pages `photos.php` and `rating.php`

I use this function to get content from ajax pages

```
function loadtab (getFile){
    $.ajax({
        url: getFile,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".tabcon").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(".tabcon").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I use jQuery fancybox plugin in `photos.php` like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css/jquery.fancybox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});

</script>
```

and this is rating page content

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".textarea").autosize();


$(".stars").click(function () {

var ratevalue = $(this).val();

$("#rate").val(ratevalue);

});

$("#formreview").submit(function(){

var yourname = $("#yourname").val();
var yourmail = $("#yourmail").val();
var rate     = $("#rate").val();
var textrev  = $("#textrev").val();

var s = {
    "yourname":yourname,
    "yourmail":yourmail,
    "rate":rate,
    "textrev":textrev
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/send_review.php",
    data: s,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(".showdata").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    },
    success: function(data){
        $(".showdata").html(data);
    }
});

return false;   
});


});
</script>
```

Notice I use the autosize jQuery plugin and I made a form to send the rate

I use tabs to get data file from contents pages my problem is when I go to tating fancybox plugin doesn't work. How can I fix that?